# Rails server return "404 Not Found" after user login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Our rails 3.2.12 app is running on `ubuntu 12.04` `passenger/nginx` server. It has been verified that both nginx and passenger are running fine. However after user login, there is 404 Not Found page thrown out. The the page is redirected to `session` instead of `user menu`. Here is the `production log` for a login (the app is running fine with the rails server locally):

```
Started GET "/nbhy" for 73.15.38.185 at 2013-05-04 20:50:55 +0000
Processing by Authentify::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/authentify-ac308b622f90/app/views/authentify/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/sessions (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 7.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

The rails app logs shows that the user has been authorized successfully. Somehow the page was redirected to session instead of user menu as it should be. We did `rake assets:precompile` and it did not help. What could cause the error? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Here is the output under .rvm/.../bundler. What we notice is that the gem authentify installed on 5/5 seems have less right than the one installed on 5/2. Is the less right on authentify the cause of the 404 page?

Also in production it is ruby 2.0.0 and it is ruby 1.9.3 in development.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-132-194-74:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwsr-x 10 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  2 04:09 authentify-784b2b097685
drwxr-xr-x 10 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  5 04:15 authentify-408e81eb022f
drwxrwsr-x 10 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  4 04:15 customerx-e1f88de5dc18
drwxrwsr-x 10 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  2 04:07 projectx-225464da5d6f
drwxr-xr-x 10 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  4 04:15 projectx-408e81ebe12b
```

Comment: Your log message says you are making GET answered with 200. Do you have something with a redirect? 302? or not found? 404?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. After a user is authorized, it should: render 'user_menus/index'. Not the /home/ubuntu/..../session/new.html.erb as shown in the log.