# Permission Denied in rvm update and rvm remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

There is `rvm 1.19.6` installed on `ubuntu 12.04` with `ruby 2.0.0`. Just receive `permission denied` when doing `rvm get stable`. Here is the error:

```
$rvm get stable
######################################################################## 100.0%
bash: line 535: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied
Could not update RVM, get some help at #rvm IRC channel at freenode servers.
```

When we are trying to installing readline on the server, the `rvm remove 2.0.0` creates the permission deny error:

```
$rvm remove 2.0.0
tee: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1367720906_remove.src.log: Permission denied
tee: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1367720906_remove.src.log: Permission denied
Removing /home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0...........
.........
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0',
please read /home/ubuntu/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1367720907_remove.rubies.log
rm: cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/ruby-2.0.0-p0': Permission denied
Removing ruby-2.0.0-p0 aliases...
Removing ruby-2.0.0-p0 wrappers...
rm: cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/ruby': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rake': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/erb': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gem': Permission denied
```

We tried to delete ~/.gem/ and assign the right to ~/.gem/specs following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303088/permission-denied-error-with-rvm), it did not work. What's wrong with the rvm? Thanks for help.

Comment: looks like you install rvm as 1 user (maybe root?) and your are trying to remove it as another?  what are the permissions and ownership on .rvm?  `ls -ld .rvm` will show. as well as the files it cannot remove.

Comment: Here is the output: drwxrwsr-x 24 root rvm 4096 May  2 04:12 .rvm       The user should be ubuntu instead of root. Is there a way we can change the ownership?

Comment: There is some strange behavior with our rails app(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379385/rails-server-return-404-not-found-after-login). Does it have something to do with this rvm problem?

Comment: The rvm was install under /home/ubuntu/.rvm. Not sure how it was assigned to root.

Comment: Now the owner was changed to ubuntu as:   drwxrwsr-x 24 ubuntu rvm 4096 May  2 04:12 .rvm   . The error is the same when rvm get stable.

Comment: did you chown -R ubuntu .rvm ?  or did you just chown the directory.  you need to make sure that all directories are owned by the same user.   Also probably doesn't have to do with your rails issue.

Comment: @Doon, I think I did. Used: $rvmsudo chown -R ubuntu ~/.rvm. There is a ruby 2.0.0@global under .rvm besides to ruby 2.0.0. Is this global for root user and should be removed?

Comment: @Doon, did $sudo chown -R ubuntu ~/.rvm again and rvm get stable works without permission error. I will mark it as answer if you have a formal reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pulling from comments.

rvm was installed as root, and needs to be owned by the ubuntu user (or you need to run all commands as root)

`sudo chown -R ubuntu .rvm` will fix the permissions errors

as for the `ruby 2.0.0@global`  it doesn't need to be removed.  if you look at the rvm documents that is used as a place to install gems that should be across all gemsets for that particular version of ruby  for instance I have `bond, hirb, wirb, awesomeprint` all in my global as they are referenced in my `.irbrc`. So as I create per project gemsets I always have them available to me (things like `bundler` are also handy there)